# How to maintain a forked git repo with feature branches that upstream won't pull?

Tags: open-source, git, workflows, forking, etiquette

So here's a typical workflow on Github...

1. Like some project `->` fork it `->` `git clone https://github.com/you/someproject`.
2. Open project.  Like what you see, but make some changes.
3. Having been careful to work only in a `feature-branch` (`git checkout -b some-feature`), you decide to make a pull request with the `upstream` maintainer - after having pushed your `feature-branch` to your Github fork.
4. Maintainer, for whatever reason, declines the pull.

For example.. [here is a failed pull request that I submitted that matches the above scenario.](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer/pull/8)..

Now *typically*, if the maintainer *HAD merged* the pull... the workflow would be simple...  On my local machine, I would commit any local changes on whatever `feature-branch` I was on at the time... `git fetch --all`, `git checkout master`, `git pull upstream --ff-only`.  Then replay my changes on top of that, as desired...

BUT...

What if I decide that you want to continue working off the changes to my fork, regrdless... yet still want to be able to track + merge changes that happen `upstream`?  Ordinarily, I would delete the feature branch, and go on my way..  How can you maintain a `master` branch that is able to be merged upstream, yet maintains your fork's features while being "permanently detached" from `upstream`'s `HEAD`?

Comment: Gratuitous changes to formatting are not going to be accepted to any single project I've ever heard of and if you insist on keeping them in your repository, welcome to your little personal well deserved merging hell. If you just cleaned up warnings, most probably it would be accepted, though you might still be asked to send it split to reasonably sized chunks. Even changes to make formatting _self-consistent_ might be accepted. But changes that change formatting to different one never are. Because everybody else is used to the current formatting and because it will cause problems with merging.

Comment: Just for context, the diff stats of the pull request is: "Showing 15 changed files with 832 additions and 1,478 deletions"

Comment: @Jan Hudec My question is about how to _use the tools_... NOT if you _like my pull request_, lol. Personally, I can't deal with a HUGE license (on an OSS project) at the top of every F-ing file, hence the large number of deletions.. and the other changes _were conventional_ and did nothing but remove compiler warnings and make the code actually readable. Regardless, this question is about how one can "work different", without being told what is "right" and "wrong".

Comment: @alexgray: That's why I am not writing it as answer, but as comment.

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of the use of your scenario, here is how you can do it:

- master is exactly of the version the upstream master has
- custom is your own "master" branch in which you have applied the formatting changes
- all feature branches are branched off custom if you don't want them to be pulled into upstream master
- Once master is updated, you rebase custom to master and then you rebase your feature branches to custom

With this strategy it should work. But keep in mind that every change you make in a feature branch based upon custom won't be accepted into upstream master.